# web api asynchronous method from .net application

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api 2 application and a wpf client. my question is that LINQ to Entities support multiple asynchronous method, like ToListAsync, ToArrayAsync and so on.

But in my wpf client application, there are no such things.

Can anyone give me some examples for asynchronous method in client application?

Comment: Actually, asynchronous methods are _very_ appropriate for WPF apps so that the UI thread can remain responsive while any background calls are in progress. Have a look at [this msdn example for wpf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh300224.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Web API calls are just straight HTTP calls. Just use the `HttpClient` class.

[Asynchronous coding reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/vstudio/hh191443%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");

// You can do work here that doesn't rely on the string from GetStringAsync.
DoIndependentWork();

string urlContents = await getStringTask;
```